# Using tso to identify outliers warning

Tags: r, machine-learning, forecasting

I'm trying to identify the outliers in my data using the code below with function `tso` from the package `tsouliers` in R.  I'm fairly certain my data has level shifts.  I'm getting the warning below.  I'm unclear what the issue is.

Code:

```
library("tsoutliers")

tsSeries<-ts(xData, frequency=168)

product.outlier<-tso(tsSeries,types=c("AO","LS","TC"))
plot(product.outlier)
```

Warning messages:

```
1: In auto.arima(x = c(11, 14, 17, 5, 5, 5.5, 8, NA, 5.5, 6.5, 8.5,  :
  Unable to fit final model using maximum likelihood. AIC value approximated
2: In auto.arima(x = c(11, 14, 17, 5, 5, 5.5, 8, NA, 5.5, 6.5, 8.5,  :
  Unable to fit final model using maximum likelihood. AIC value approximated
```

I updated my code and added `na.approx`.  The code now finds outliers in the data, and returns the set of warnings below.  Why is the code now finding outliers when before it didn't?  Are these legitimate outliers?  What do the warnings below mean, are there settings I should change in tso to resolve them?  All tips very much appreciated.

```
##Updated Code

test<-ts(na.approx(xData), frequency=168)

product.outlier<-tso(test,types=c("AO","LS","TC"))
```

Warning messages:

```
1: In auto.arima(x = c(11, 14, 17, 5, 5, 5.5, 8, 6.75, 5.5, 6.5, 8.5,  :
  Unable to fit final model using maximum likelihood. AIC value approximated
2: In sqrt(diag(fit$var.coef)[id]) : NaNs produced
3: In auto.arima(x = c(11, 14, 17, 5, 5, 5.5, 8, 6.75, 5.5, 6.5, 8.5,  :
  Unable to fit final model using maximum likelihood. AIC value approximated
4: In auto.arima(x = c(11, 14, 17, 5, 5, 5.5, 8, 6.75, 5.5, 6.5, 8.5,  :
  Unable to fit final model using maximum likelihood. AIC value approximated
```

Data:

```
dput(xData)
c(11, 14, 17, 5, 5, 5.5, 8, NA, 5.5, 6.5, 8.5, 4, 5, 9, 10, 11, 
7, 6, 7, 7, 5, 6, 9, 9, 6.5, 9, 3.5, 2, 15, 2.5, 17, 5, 5.5, 
7, 6, 3.5, 6, 9.5, 5, 7, 4, 5, 4, 9.5, 3.5, 5, 4, 4, 9, 4.5, 
6, 10, NA, 9.5, 15, 9, 5.5, 7.5, 12, 17.5, 19, 7, 14, 17, 3.5, 
6, 15, 11, 10.5, 11, 13, 9.5, 9, 7, 4, 6, 15, 5, 18, 5, 6, 19, 
19, 6, 7, 7.5, 7.5, 7, 6.5, 9, 10, 5.5, 5, 7.5, 5, 4, 10, 7, 
5, 12, 6, NA, 4, 2, 5, 7.5, 11, 13, 7, 8, 7.5, 5.5, 7.5, 15, 
7, 4.5, 9, 3, 4, 6, 17.5, 11, 7, 6, 7, 4.5, 4, 4, 5, 10, 14, 
7, 7, 4, 7.5, 11, 6, 11, 7.5, 15, 23.5, 8, 12, 5, 9, 10, 4, 9, 
6, 8.5, 7.5, 6, 5, 8, 6, 5.5, 8, 11, 10.5, 4, 6, 7, 10, 11.5, 
11.5, 3, 4, 16, 3, 2, 2, 8, 4.5, 7, 4, 8, 11, 6.5, 7.5, 17, 6, 
6.5, 9, 12, 17, 10, 5, 5, 9, 3, 8.5, 11, 4.5, 7, 16, 11, 14, 
6.5, 15, 8.5, 7, 6.5, 11, 2, 2, 13.5, 4, 2, 16, 11.5, 3.5, 9, 
16.5, 2.5, 4.5, 8.5, 5, 6, 7.5, 9.5, NA, 9.5, 8, 2.5, 4, 12, 
13, 10, 4, 6, 16, 16, 13, 8, 12, 19, 19, 5.5, 8, 6.5, NA, NA, 
NA, 15, 12, NA, 6, 11, 8, 4, 2, 3, 4, 10, 7, 5, 4.5, 4, 5, 11.5, 
12, 10.5, 4.5, 3, 4, 7, 15.5, 9.5, NA, 9.5, 12, 13.5, 10, 10, 
13, 6, 8.5, 15, 16.5, 9.5, 14, 9, 9.5, 11, 15, 14, 5.5, 6, 14, 
16, 9.5, 23, NA, 19, 12, 5, 11, 16, 8, 11, 9, 13, 6, 7, 3, 5.5, 
7.5, 19, 6.5, 5.5, 4.5, 7, 8, 7, 10, 11, 13, NA, 12, 1.5, 7, 
7, 12, 8, 6, 9, 15, 9, 3, 5, 11, 11, 8, 6, 3, 7.5, 4, 7, 7.5, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 6.5, 2, 16.5, 7.5, 8, 8, 5, 2, 7, 4, 6.5, 4.5, 
10, 6, 4.5, 6.5, 9, 2, 6, 3.5, NA, 5, 7, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 13, 19, 
8.5, 10, 8, 13, 10, 10, 6, 13.5, 12, 11, 5.5, 6, 3.5, 9, 8, NA, 
6, 5, 8.5, 3, 12, 10, 9.5, 7, 24, 7, 9, 11.5, 5, 7, 11, 6, 5.5, 
3, 4.5, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4.5, 6, 10, 5, 4, 4, 9.5, 5, 7, 6, 3, 13, 
5.5, 5, 7.5, 3, 5, 6.5, 5, 5.5, 6, 4, 3, 5, NA, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
5, 5.5, 9, 6, 8.5, 9.5, 8, 9, 6, 12, 5, 7, 5, 3.5, 4, 7.5, 7, 
5, 4, 4, NA, 7, 5.5, 6, 8.5, 6.5, 9, 3, 2, 8, 15, 6, 4, 10, 7, 
13, 14, 9.5, 9, 18, 6, 5, 4, 6, 4, 11.5, 17.5, 7, 8, 10, 4, 7, 
5, 9, 6, 5, 4, 8, 4, 2, 1.5, 3.5, 6, 5.5, 5, 4, 8, 10.5, 4, 11, 
9.5, 5, 6, 11, 21, 9.5, 11, 13.5, 7.5, 13, 10, 7, 9.5, 6, 10, 
5.5, 6.5, 12, 10, 10, 6.5, 2, 8, NA, 10, 5, 4, 4.5, 5, 7.5, 12, 
22, 5, 8.5, 2.5, 3, 10.5, 4, 7, 13, 4, 3, 5, 6.5, 3, 9, 9.5, 
16, NA, 4, 12, 4.5, 7, 5.5, 8, 14, 3, 8, 12, 14, 7, 8, 6, 8.5, 
6, 6.5, 15.5, 13, 3.5, 12, 7, 6, NA, 3, 5.5, 8.5, 9, 12, 13, 
8, 6.5, 8, 3, 5, 16.5, 2, 7, 6, 2, 5, 6.5, 3, 3, 7, 2, NA, 13, 
7, 16, 13, 12.5, 12, 7, 13, 11, 21.5, 16, 20, 3, 4, 5, 7, 11, 
7, 9, 11, 7, 13, 4, 14, 5, 12, 6, 7, 9, 12, 7, 12.5, 6.5, 16, 
5, 12, 9, 9.5, 9, 7, 9.5, 3, 13, 8, 7, 7, 7, 9, 6, 6, 11, 15, 
9, 6, 19, 10.5, 4, 6, 14.5, 9, 17, 14, 4, 16, 5, 6.5)
```

Comment: I ran your code and no outlier has been detected

Comment: @adiana Did you have to change the code at all to avoid getting the error message?  I'm running R 3.2.4 Revised, is that the version you are running?

Comment: I'm using 3.2.3, but I imagine is the package version which makes the difference

Comment: @adiana I re-installed the tsoutliers package, and now instead of an error I get the warning.  I've updated the post with the warning.  Do you know what the warning means?  Also when I try to run the code to plot, I get the message below.  plot(product.outlier)
‘x’ does not contain outliers to display
NULL

Comment: Are you sure it is detecting any outlier?